# sql query: display names of player those who play Soccer as well as Tennis

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in mysql database: `PLAYERS`,`SPORTS` and `INTERESTS`

`PLAYERS` table contains id and player name `(id,player_name)`

Data example:

```
(1,David) 
(2,Jack)
(3,Ron)
(4,Smith)
```

`SPORTS` table contains id and sports name  `(id,sports_name)`

Data example:

```
(1,Soccer)
(2,Tennis)
(3,Swimming)
```

Each players might be interested in multiple sports so `INTERESTS` table has player id and sports id. `(player_id,sports_id)`

Data example:

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)
```

I want to display names of player those who play Soccer as well as Tennis.
Not Soccer or Tennis but Soccer and Tennis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think something like this might work:

```
SELECT
  player_name
FROM
  players
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT id FROM interests i WHERE i.player_id = players.id AND i.sports_id = 1)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM interests i WHERE i.player_id = players.id AND i.sports_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select P.id, P.player_name
From Players As P
    Join Interests As I
        On I.player_id = P.id
    Join Sports As S
        On S.id = I.sports_id
Where S.sports_name In('Tennis','Soccer')
Group By P.id, P.player_name
Having Count( Distinct S.sports_name ) = 2
```

Comment: I think you'll probably want to group by something other than player name, right? The player.id column is unique, but I wouldn't assume that the player_name is. I think this would give us an error if player (1, 'Bob Smith') likes soccer and player (2, 'Bob Smith') likes Tennis.

Comment: You also should make sure there's a unique constraint on (player_id,sports_id) in the interests table (or otherwise ensure that all the rows stay unique). Because otherwise a single player could list his interest in soccer twice and would be selected by the query.

Comment: @drewbob - How would a user know whether they were looking at a duplicate or not? I.e., how does the user know whether (1,Bob Smith) is really the same as (2,Bob Smith). Still, an easy fix.

Comment: @Roy - Actually, Count( Distinct S.sports_name ) takes care of the same player having the same interest twice.

Comment: @Roy - I'm not talking about duplicates. I'm talking about distinct players with the same name. We wouldn't want to accidentally include Bob Smith if he likes _only_ tennis and his like-named friend likes _only_ soccer.

Comment: @drewbob - Perhaps I should rephrase my response. `Group By P.player_name` should be `Group By <business key including name>`. Thus, if name is not unique, we'd need something else to uniquely identify the person beyond the surrogate key. However, a simple fix is to group by the surrogate key but it obviously won't solve the problem of "Why is Bob Smith listed twice in my results?"

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the help